# Weblogic 9.2 webservice client SOAP Fault due to SOAPMessage content-type not supported in new server

Tags: java, soap

There is tech refresh project in my company. and we are buying a new system from the marketing and trying to integrate it with our existing systems. 
as there are hundreds of existing systems need to be integrated. we designed reuse current demolishing system interfaces and expose them in our new systems.

Due to our new system framework issue, it cannot expose a webservice endpoint URL to our existing systems. instead, it is providing a wrapper servlet URL and it is working for almost systems except a system which running on weblogic 9.2. 
it is hitting Soap fault error (`http 500 - Internal Server Error`) and connection failed with new system.

```
java.rmi.RemoteException: SOAPFaultException - FaultCode [{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server] FaultString [Failed to receive message java.io.IOException: The server at *http://***.***.***.***:8080/servlet/SoapAdapter* returned a 500 error code (Internal Server Error).
```

We found that it is working on Weblogic 10 above, but just cannot work on weblogic 9.2. We spent around 2 weeks to find out the root cause, but still no outcome.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Yesterday, I used Fiddler to catch the http package and compare the difference between weblogic 10 and weblogic 9. I found that the content type was different between them;

When we tried weblogic 10, I found the content type was[*`Content-Type: text/xml`*]; but when tried weblogic 9.2, we found that content type was[*`text/xml; charset="utf-8"`*]. Very strange here that weblogic 9.2 is sending charset at the behind.

So I implement a soap handling to override the content-type in `SoapMessage MimeHeaders;` it works!

Below is my soap handler code:

```
SOAPMessageContext soapMessageContext = (SOAPMessageContext) context;
SOAPMessage message = soapMessageContext.getMessage();
MimeHeaders soapMimeHeader = message.getMimeHeaders();
soapMimeHeader.removeHeader("Content-Type");
soapMimeHeader.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
soapMimeHeader.addHeader("charset", "UTF-8");
```